# Find papers authored by a specific number of authors

Tags: literature-search, bibliometrics, scopus, pubmed, web-of-science

For some concrete study, I need to find for some keywords, papers that have just one author. I used PubMed, Scopus and ISI Web of Science, but in any case, I could not find a way to filter bibliographic search results by a specific number of authors, or a number less than some exact number of authors. Anybody knows how to do this with mentioned tools (PubMed, Scopus and ISI Web of Science) or others?

Comment: *For some concrete study* --- When I began reading your question I thought it was about a study involving [concrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete)! (e.g. From a materials science perspective, from an engineering construction perspective, from a business cost perspective, etc.) However, as I was reading your 2nd sentence I realized what you meant . . .

Comment: anyway, it could also be related to scientific studies about concrete, asphalt, etc, why not? and ... is it relevant?

Comment: I asked this question in chat, Ivvory tower, but my question was about subject, something like keyword or specific topic, and I went to library, I mean librarian there was some kind of conference for web of knowleadge and they explained also your topic in question, but I forogot sicne it was not my focus, give me few days and I will go again to library to ask for this.

Comment: After a quick google search: The author of this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.4863) claims that "of the 1.3 million publications [...] 2011 [...] in the Web of Science database, 89% had more than one author.", so it might be worth to ask him how he obtained this number, maybe you can use his method.

Comment: that is a good idea, I will ask him/her

Comment: What computational resources do you have at your disposal? My suspicion is that the authors in the study mentioned by @DirkLiebhold either brute-forced it (downloaded all the publications' metadata, had a program count the authors, and calculated the distribution of counts) or had a contact at Web of Science run the query.

Comment: yes, that might be the reason. and a good approach. what I will do, is just to download the specific results of my search, as CSV, and then process them in excel for one single author records

Comment: @flow have you tried to contact support team of science direct or ISI? they are fast with replies

Comment: If you are interested in Computer Science papers, DBLP might be interesting (http://dblp.uni-trier.de/statistics/numberofauthorsperpublication.html for a quick count). The DBLP collection can be downloaded and is small enough to process on a desktop system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PubMed has an interface which you can call from a script. The intend to develop it is exactly your class of problem, which cannot be solved from the provided user interface.

This is the main page of NCBI Entrez API:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/

What you need to do is to query PubMed by keyword(s), for example this is a search by "concrete":

https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=json&retmax=100&sort=relevance&term=concrete

Do multiple queries, to cover your field, for example you can also consider "brick" or "cement".

It returns a list of publications. For each publication, you would have to check the number of authors and keep ones with a single author. For each publication, you shall call:

https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=29510510&retmode=json

Determine the size of the vector "authors", and only keep the ones of size one.

Comment: can you elaborate about how to determine the size of vector authors?

Comment: sorry for downvote, that was completely unintentional. I'll change that as soon as possible!

Comment: @OUb no problem, I've upvoted yours, good work!

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Razvan P's hint, I wrote a little python3-script which solves your problem:

```
'''
Created on 01.04.2018

@author: OBu
'''

import requests
import json
from collections import Counter # for histogram

eutils_basepath = 'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/'
DB = 'pubmed'           # please modify for other databases
RETMAX = '100'          # max 100 results - modify if needed, maximum = 100.000
SEARCHTERM = "concrete" # replace with your search term

# Now build the search URL:
search_url = eutils_basepath + 'esearch.fcgi?db=' + DB + \
                               '&retmode=json&retmax=' + RETMAX + \
                               '&sort=relevance&term=' + SEARCHTERM
# for additional search parameters or mor complex search terms see examples in
# https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/#chapter1.Searching_a_Database
# or the full doc under 
# https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/#chapter4.ESearch

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(search_url)
if r.status_code != 200:
    raise ConnectionError("Search failed with error code " + str(r.status_code))
search_results = json.loads(r.text)

#show some statistics
print(f"{search_results['esearchresult']['count']} publications found.")
if RETMAX < search_results['esearchresult']['count']:
    print(f"Warning: Only the first {RETMAX} publications are processed.")

# walk through all rerieved ids and fetch detailed publication information
# An alternative soloution could use one single query based on the previous search results as shown in 
# https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/#_chapter1_Downloading_Document_Summaries_
# This would reduce the server load
histogram = Counter()
for pub_id in search_results['esearchresult']['idlist']:
    #print(f"Fetching {pub_id}", end=" ") # uncomment for a more verbose versione
    # Now build the fetch URL:
    fetch_url = eutils_basepath + 'esummary.fcgi?db=' + DB + '&retmode=json&id=' + pub_id
    r = s.get(fetch_url)
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise ConnectionError(f"Fetching of publication {pub_id} failed with error code {r.status_code}")
#     else: # uncomment for a more verbose versione
#         print("...success!") # uncomment for a more verbose versione
    fetch_result = json.loads(r.text)
    authors = fetch_result['result'][pub_id]['authors']
    if len(authors) == 1:
        print(f"UID: {pub_id}, author: {authors[0]['name']}, title: {fetch_result['result'][pub_id]['title']}")
    histogram[len(authors)] += 1    

print("Histogram: (number of authors, number of papers with that many authors)")
print(sorted(histogram.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

You will need python 3.6 or above to run this script (please remove f-strings for earlier versions, and you'll hvae to install "requests" via `pip install requests`.

The script searches for the SEARCHTERM in pubmed and for the search term `concrete` (I like this running gag ;-) ) produces an output like

```
14125 publications found.
Warning: Only the first 100 publications are processed.
UID: 28844248, author: Baroody AJ, title: The Use of Concrete Experiences in Early Childhood Mathematics Instruction.
UID: 28772472, author: Wang XY, title: Modeling of Hydration, Compressive Strength, and Carbonation of Portland-Limestone Cement (PLC) Concrete.
UID: 29159238, author: Paul SC, title: Data on optimum recycle aggregate content in production of new structural concrete.
UID: 27012788, author: Kovler K, title: The national survey of natural radioactivity in concrete produced in Israel. 
Histogram: (number of authors, number of papers with that many authors)
[(1, 4), (2, 15), (3, 21), (4, 24), (5, 19), (6, 10), (7, 3), (8, 2), (10, 2)]
```

It should not be too difficult to modify the script for other search tasks...

If there are questions on how to use the script, please ask!